# How to add additional conditions to WHERE clause in SQL pagination query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have pagination query which is executed on `SQL SERVER 2008 rs2` and looks like so :

```
SELECT ClientId, FirstName, LastName
FROM ( SELECT tbl.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ClientId ASC ) AS rownum FROM 
[MyDb].[dbo].[Client] as tbl )
seq  WHERE seq.rownum BETWEEN 0 AND 10
```

and it's working fine. However I have filters and sometimes I need to add additional clauses `LIKE %...` and stuff like that. But I can't figure out where's the place to do that. I tried:

```
 seq  WHERE seq.rownum BETWEEN 0 AND 10 AND FirstName LIKE %Jh%
```

But I get error. How to add my additional filtering clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need single quotes around `%Jh%`:

```
seq  WHERE seq.rownum BETWEEN 0 AND 10 AND FirstName LIKE '%Jh%'
```